# Taking multiple %s inputs in c

Tags: c

I am trying to take inputs in C. I am using multiple `scanf` but it takes only one input and then exits. Here is my code-

/*Approach-
I created  structure of type account and in funciton create_account user
enter the details of the account.

Algorithm-
In function withdraw if user withdraw, balance is subtraced, in function 
deposited, if user deposited balance is added witj deposited ammount,
in funcion display, information is displaed

Implmentation-
It is below.

Results-

Summary-
It can be improved further by maintaing a database of users and their information
*/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct account
{
    char * bank_branch;
    char * bank_name;
    char * acc_holder_name;
    int acc_no;
    char * acc_holder_add;
    float balance;
}account;


account * acc;
int acc_no=0;
void create_account()
{
    printf("Enter bank branch\n");
    scanf("%s",acc->bank_branch);

    printf("Enter bank_name\n");
    scanf("%s",acc->bank_name);
    printf("Enter account holder name\n");
    scanf("%s",acc->acc_holder_name);
    printf("Enter account holder address\n");
    scanf("%s",acc->acc_holder_add);

    acc->acc_no=acc_no;
    acc_no+1;
    acc->balance=0;
}


void display_info()
{

    printf("Bank branch=%s\n", acc->bank_branch);
    printf("Bank Name=%s\n", acc->bank_name);
    printf("Account holder name=%s\n",acc->acc_holder_name );
    printf("Account holder address=%s\n",acc->acc_holder_add );
    printf("Account number=%d\n",acc->acc_no );
    printf("Balance=%f\n",acc->balance );


}

int main()
{
     //creating a variable acc of type account
    acc=malloc(sizeof(account));
    create_account();
    display_info();
}
```

After I enter bank branch, it does not take any further inputs. Why is this happening?

Comment: Use `scanf(" %s"...` You will need to understand that `scanf` leaves the `'\n'` in the input buffer as the `%s` format character reads up to the first *whitespace* or `'\n'`. Include a 'space' before the `%s` to force `scanf` to skip over the `'\n'` (which is considered whitespace). If you are going to use the `scanf` functions, then spend time with `man scanf` it will save you much time later. You will probably want use `fgets` for general input.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `%s` already consumes leading whitespace; your suggestion makes no difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [cplusplus.com scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) :

> The additional arguments should point to already allocated objects of
>   the type specified by their corresponding format specifier within the
>   format string.

In your structure account you do not allocate memory for `char *` arguments then your program will crash when it call `scanf`.

Either replace `char *` by `char[N]` where N is the size of the char table or for each `char *` argument of your structure use malloc or calloc.

Comment: I did what you suggested but now sometime it works and sometime it exits before taking all the inputs.

Comment: Can you update the code with the changes you made and the sequence of inputs which made the program exiting before the end ?

Comment: Thanks, one of the reasons for my program to exit was as you pointed out that I was not allocating memory. Another reason was that I was using taking inputs which had whitespaces, and so scanf was treating them as the next input. Using fgets as pointed out by David fixed this problem.